# Accelerating the prediction

Tags: scikit-learn

Prediction with the SVM model created with 5 features and 3000 samples using default parameters is taking unexpectedely longer time (more than hour) with 5 features and 100000 samples. Is there way of accelerating the prediction?

Comment: This is not the case with other classifiers, e.g., Random Forest so I am asking.

Comment: interesting...which Penalty parameter C are you using?

Comment: @omerbp I do not know- I just used clf = SVC(); clf.fit(X, y); and clf.predict()

Comment: @Borys I've modified my answer to include some codes to demonstrate how to use grid search cross validation to choose best parameters for `SVC` algo. If you find that helpful, please accept and upvote my answer. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues to consider here:

1. Have you standardized your input matrix X? SVM is not scale-invariant, so it could be difficult for the algo to do classification if they takes a large number of raw inputs without proper scaling.
2. The choice of parameter `C`: Higher `C` allows a more complicated non-smooth decision boundary and it takes much more time to fit under this complexity. So decreasing the value `C` from default 1 to a lower value could accelerate the process.
3. It's also recommended to choose a proper value of `gamma`. This could be done via Grid-Search-Cross-Validation.

Here is the code to do grid-search cross validation. I ignore the test set here for simplicity.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score, make_scorer

# generate some artificial data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=3000, n_features=5, weights=[0.1, 0.9])

# make a pipeline for convenience
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='auto'))

# set up parameter space, we want to tune SVC params C and gamma
# the range below is 10^(-5) to 1 for C and 0.01 to 100 for gamma
param_space = dict(svc__C=np.logspace(-5,0,5), svc__gamma=np.logspace(-2, 2, 10))

# choose your customized scoring function, popular choices are f1_score, accuracy_score, recall_score, roc_auc_score
my_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, greater_is_better=True)
# construct grid search
gscv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_space, scoring=my_scorer)
gscv.fit(X, y)
# what's the best estimator
gscv.best_params_

Out[20]: {'svc__C': 1.0, 'svc__gamma': 0.21544346900318834}

# what's the best score, in our case, roc_auc_score
gscv.best_score_

Out[22]: 0.86819366014152421
```

Note: the SVC is still not running very fast. It takes more than 40s to compute 50 possible combinations of params.

```
%time gscv.fit(X, y)
CPU times: user 42.6 s, sys: 959 ms, total: 43.6 s
Wall time: 43.6 s
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you show me how to use gamma via grid-search-cross-validation?

Comment: @Borys http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html

Comment: @yangjie, Jianxun Li I tried to use your solution for getting parameters for DT classifier. However, I got the following error: ValueError: Invalid parameter max_depth for estimator Pipeline. Does not it works for different classifier?

Comment: @Borys If you want to specify a parameter of a particular step in pipeline, you need to use this syntax `<your_step_name>__<your_parameter>` where there is a `double underscore` to link these two part. For the error you saw, try this `'decisiontreeclassifier__max_depth': np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

Comment: @yangjie I got error when using with multi-class. How can I make it work with multi-class case?

Comment: @yangjie, Jianxun Li ValueError: multiclass format is not supported

Answer (score 1):

Because the number of features is relatively low, I would start with decreasing the penalty parameter. It controls the penalty for mislabeled samples in the train data, and as your data contains 5 features, I guess it is not exactly linearly separable.

Generally, this parameter (`C`) allows the classifier to have larger margin on the account of higher accuracy (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) for more information)

By default, `C=1.0`. Start with `svm = SVC(C=0.1)` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

One reason might be that the parameter `gamma` is not the same.

By default `sklearn.svm.SVC` uses RBF kernel and `gamma` is 0.0, in which case 1/n_features will be used instead. So `gamma` is different given different number of features.

In terms of suggestions, I agree with [Jianxun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31125749/1319871).

Comment: If I change gamma during learning, should I also select the chosen features during prediction? Or can I input all the features during prediction? If I need to choose the same features utilized during learning for the prediction. How can I know the used feature names, given that the features are ['a','b','c','d','e']

Comment: Well, I think you have some misunderstanding. 1/n_features is just the default value of `gamma` if you do not specify `gamma`. If you manually choose the `gamma`, then there is nothing to do with the number of features. In both cases, all the features will be used.

Comment: Aha I got it. So if I have to choose the best features, I have to go through pipeline and SelectKBest in case of SVC, am I right?

Comment: Exactly. That would be a different problem.