# Does GridSearchCV not support multi-class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to use GridSearchCV for multi-class case based on the answer from here:

[Accelerating the prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109192/accelerating-the-prediction/31125749?noredirect=1#comment50490112_31125749)

But I got value error, `multiclass format is not supported.`

How can I use this method for multi-class case?

Following code is from the answer in above link.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score, make_scorer

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=3000, n_features=5, weights=[0.1, 0.9, 0.3])

pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='auto'))

param_space = dict(svc__C=np.logspace(-5,0,5), svc__gamma=np.logspace(-2, 2, 10))

accuracy_score, recall_score, roc_auc_score
my_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, greater_is_better=True)

gscv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_space, scoring=my_scorer)
gscv.fit(X, y)

print gscv.best_params_
```

Comment: Gotta post your code. We can't help if we don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation on [roc_auc_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score):

> Note: this implementation is restricted to the binary classification task or multilabel classification task in label indicator format.

By "label indicator format", they mean each label value is represented as a binary column (rather than as a unique target value in a single column). You don't want to do that for your predictor, as it could result in non-mutually-exclusive predictions (i.e., predicting both label 2 and 4 for case p1, or predicting no labels for case p2).

Pick or custom-implement a scoring function that is well-defined for the multiclass problem, such as [F1 score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score). Personally I find [informedness](http://www.flinders.edu.au/science_engineering/fms/School-CSEM/publications/tech_reps-research_artfcts/TRRA_2007.pdf) more convincing than F1 score, and easier to generalize to the multiclass problem than roc_auc_score.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1,and accepted. So informedness is not currently available in scikit-learn?

Comment: Not version 0.15, which I use. I don't think it's in 0.16 either.

Comment: So what sofware or program do you use for it?

Comment: I wrote my own implementation. I would have shared it, but it doesn't support multiclass as I don't need that.

Comment: Please share the informedness code with the group, or any example you have of implementing a multi-output classifier metric.

Comment: @Andreus The docs for [roc_auc_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) seem to have been updated since and it says "Note: this implementation can be used with binary, multiclass and multilabel classification, but some restrictions apply (see Parameters)" What restrictions should I be paying attention to here? Appreciate if you can refer the doc and tell me where to focus.

Comment: Apologies, @Hawklaz, haven't been on for a bit. It would appear the documentation has been further updated since you asked your question; if you still need information, can you check and see whether your question is answered there?

Answer (score 5):

It supports multi-class
You can set the para of `scoring = f1.macro`, example:

```
gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = est1, param_grid=params_test1, scoring='f1_macro', cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
```

Or scoring = `'roc_auc_ovr'`

Answer (score 1):

It supports multi-class naturally if the classifier has the correct API by default for `y_true` and `y_pred`/`y_score`.

Otherwise, one has to do some customization using the score function like [`make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html).

For [common metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) like AUROC for multi-classes, sklearn offers the `'roc_auc_ovr'`, where it actually refers to

```
roc_auc_ovr_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_proba=True,
                                 multi_class='ovr')
```

as in the [source file](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a9cc0ed86fca1480acbd8aaf211f062ee2abd5b7/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L673).

To deal with multi-class problem with a classifier like e.g.,`LogisticRegression`, `ovr` is required and `y_true` is in the format of categorical values. The above setting will work directly.

Some other metrics for binary classifications can also be extended by wrapping the respective function. E.g., [`average_precision_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score) can be wrapped as

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


def multi_auprc(y_true_cat, y_score):
    y_true = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(y_true_cat.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
    
    return average_precision_score(y_true, y_score)
```

The metric can then be defined for GridsearchCV as

```
{
'auprc': make_scorer(multi_auprc, needs_proba=True, greater_is_better=True)    
}
```